# what does it mean to store cross products in SAR product data file?

Tags: remote-sensing, radar

I'm reading the [UAVSAR data format](http://uavsar.jpl.nasa.gov/science/documents/polsar-format.html)
For definition of two types of file we have:

> **MLC files (.mlc):** calibrated multi-looked **cross products**, floating
> point format, three files8 bytes per pixel, three files 4 bytes per
> pixel, little endian.
>
> **Ground projected files (.grd):** calibrated complex **cross products**
> projected to the ground in simple geographic coordinates (latitude,
> longitude). There is a fixed number of looks for each pixel. Floating
> point, little endian, 8 or 4 bytes per pixel.

I know that the schematic form of SLC file is like this:
[image]
where **I** and **Q** are successively the real and imaginary part of the complex signal for each pixel after sampling and analog to digital conversion but if I take cross product as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), how can I imagine **MLC** or **GRD** format schematically?
I mean which components in the SLC file are multiplied by each other to form the cross product of each pixel?
What does cross product of the pixel mean in a physical sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we study [UAVSAR data format](http://uavsar.jpl.nasa.gov/science/documents/polsar-format.html) completely, it is said that:

> - MLC data:
>
>   The MLC is a pure binary file with no header bytes. Three of the
>     files are complex floating point, 8 byte per pixel. These complex
>     products are derived from the average (usually 3 pixels in range, and
>     12 pixels in azimuth, given precisely by " Number of Range Looks in
>     MLC " and "Number of Azimuth Looks in MLC" in the annotation file) of
>     the product of each SLC pixel and correspond to:
>
>   ```
>                                         ShhShv*
>
>                                         ShhSvv*  
>
>                                         ShvSvv*
>   ```
>
>   Three of the files are real floating point, 4 bytes per pixel. These
>     real powers are derived from the average (usually 3 pixels in range,
>     and 12 pixels in azimuth, given precsely by " Number of Range Looks in
>     MLC " and "Number of Azimuth Looks in MLC" in the annotation file) of
>     the product of each SLC pixel and correspond to:
>
>   ```
>                                         ShhShh*   
>
>                                         ShvShv*   
>
>                                         SvvSvv*
>   ```

and

> - GRD data:
>
>   The grd files consists of three real floating point, 4 bytes per
>     pixel, and three complex floating point, 8 bytes per pixel files. The
>     number of lines and samples may be found in the annotation file and
>     are given by grd_mag.set_rows and grd_mag.set_cols respectively. The
>     grd files contain projected multi-looked data for crossproducts HHHH,
>     HVHV, VVVV, HHHV, HVHV, and HVVV:
>
>   ```
>                                        ShhShv*  
>
>                                        ShhSvv*  
>
>                                        ShvSvv*  
>
>                                        ShhShh*   
>
>                                        ShvShv*  
>
>                                        SvvSvv*
>   ```

From the four **SLC** files that [image] is stored in each of them and for the monostatic backscattering case [image] we can form the scattering matrix as follows:
[image]
for each pixel. If we take the Lexicographic matrix basis set as follows:
[image]
We can make the `3-D Lexicographic feature vector`:
[image]
now we can acquire the `covariance matrix` for each pixel from the ensemble average of the cross product of `3-D Lexicographic feature vector` **(hear cross product is the same as tensor product or outer product)**
[image]
which is a hermitian matrix. So we have 6 files, 3 are complex floating point and the off-diagonal terms of the covariance matrix (without the constant coefficient) is stored in them and the other 3 are floating point and the diagonal terms of the covariance matrix is stored in them.
As said ensemble averaging is done by 3 pixels in range, and 12 pixels in azimuth